# Impossible to call application (URL Scheme) from UIWebView in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7

A bit of an odd situation. We work with an outside partner, which exposes a webpage where their users can log in. This webpage takes a parameter called `returnURL`. This `returnURL` will be called upon successful login to their service and at the end of this return URL our outside partner will add a token that we can use afterwards in the application.

Because I work in iOS, as a returnURL I am giving my application's URL scheme, so that the webpage can call it when the login is done.

So, it goes like this. Their webpage:

`http://www.theirwebpage.com/?param1=x&param2=y&returnURL=myAppsName://`

I show the webpage in a webview and within `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` I have the code for the return, where I parse the parameters passed with `myAppsName://`

**The Problem**

This whole process works fine on iOS 6, as the webview will call the URL scheme of the application, which will trigger `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`.

However, the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method never gets called in iOS 7. It seems more like the webview calls itself the `myAppsName://{parameters}` and then fails (for a further explanation, the UIWebView calls `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` and within its `NSErrorFailingURLKey` we can find the full `myAppsName://extraParam1=bar&token=foo`).

Is there a change that happened in iOS 7, where this type of call (from a UIWebView to the application itself) is no longer permitted?

Comment: It works for me in iOS 7 as you describe, although I am also getting an error when the UIWebView attempts to load the request at the custom URL scheme (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427009/uiwebview-load-fails-with-custom-url-scheme). Are you sure that you've registered the *myAppsName* custom URL scheme in your app's plist according to the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50

Answer (score 0):

Problem with xcode 5.0 . Download the xcode version 5.0.1 . Clean all the builds ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/~ . Build again.